# Prevent view overlapping in RelativeLayout

Tags: android, android-relativelayout

I'm trying to accomplish a simple layout task, but I'm stuck with view overlapping in `RelativeLayout`.

Screenshot:

[image]

The title `TextView` should always be centered (both vertically and horizontally). The problem is when the  title is a bit longer and it covers the back `Button`.

The desired behaviour is that the title `TextView` aligns left with the back Button, or eventually trims (e.g. `singleLine`).

Here is my XML:

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:orientation="vertical">

    <RelativeLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="50dp"
        android:background="#ffffff">

        <LinearLayout
            android:id="@+id/backbutton"
            android:layout_width="100dp"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:background="#cccccc">

            <TextView
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:gravity="center"
                android:text=" < Back"
                android:textSize="20sp" />
        </LinearLayout>

        <TextView
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
            android:gravity="start|center_vertical"
            android:text="Centered title"
            android:textSize="22sp" />
    </RelativeLayout>

    <RelativeLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="50dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="30dp"
        android:background="#ffffff">

        <LinearLayout
            android:id="@+id/backbutton2"
            android:layout_width="100dp"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:background="#cccccc">

            <TextView
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:gravity="center"
                android:text=" < Back"
                android:textSize="20sp" />
        </LinearLayout>

        <TextView
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
            android:gravity="center"
            android:text="A very long centered title"
            android:textSize="22sp" />
    </RelativeLayout>
</LinearLayout>
```

Comment: @Der Gol...lum the title could be longer, so your advice is not applicable, particularly when displaying on devices with smaller width.

Comment: Oh, oh... why all this **horrible layout nesting**?

Comment: @DerGol...lum it's just a demo

Comment: Use `android:layout_width="match_parent"` instead of `android:layout_width="wrap_content"`. Contrary to what you might think, `match_parent` only fills the **remaining** space.

Answer (score 0):

I don't think you can do that via XML. I would calculate that at runtime. Put a text into your `TextView` and calculate its width in pixels. By default it will be centered, but, if its width is bigger than `screenWidth - 2 * backButtonWidth`, then it shouldn't be centered but aligned to back button edge and trimmed at the end.

Answer (score 0):

You can try something like this for the back button line. 
You can change Back button and the placeholder to use weight as well.
This by default truncate the long text on tail.

```
<LinearLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:orientation="horizontal">

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="100dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:background="#cccccc"
        android:text="< Back"/>

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/button_search"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:singleLine="true"
        android:text="Title"/>

    <View                 <!--- Placeholder -->
        android:layout_width="100dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" />

</LinearLayout>
```

Answer (score -1):

First of all it's a wrong approach to implement this layout.You can create this layout by using only Linear Layout:- Try this:`

```
<LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/linearLayout1"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="horizontal" >

    <TextView
            android:id="@+id/textView1"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="Back"
            android:layout_gravity="left"/>

    <TextView
            android:id="@+id/textView2"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginLeft="20dp"
            android:text="456546546"
            android:singleLine="true"
            android:ellipsize="end"
            android:layout_gravity="right" />

</LinearLayout>

<LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/linearLayout2"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="horizontal" >

    <TextView
            android:id="@+id/textView3"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="Back"
            android:layout_gravity="left"/>

    <TextView
            android:id="@+id/textView4"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginLeft="20dp"
            android:text="456546546"
            android:singleLine="true"
            android:ellipsize="end"
            android:layout_gravity="right" />

</LinearLayout>
```

`